# Why are towgs84 definitions missing on Ubuntu 12.04 compared to Windows?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Why for some of my most used CRS the 'towgs84' part of the definition of the layer spatial reference system is missing, compared to the QGIS for Windows?

EPSG 3004, 23032, 23033 when used with QGIS for Ubuntu are missing the 'towgs84' definition part, that is present in QGIS for Windos. Why this?

I've experimented this with QGIS 1.8 for Win and QGIS 1.8 and 1.9 Master under Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRS database of QGIS normally gets syncronized against the GDAL/PROJ CRS definition files at the end of the installation process. If the installation fails, or you had an older version of GDAL/PROJ installed on Ubuntu, you might have outdated CRS information stored in the database.

As a workaround, you could make a copy of `C:\Programme\QuantumGISLisboa\apps\qgis\resources\srs.db`, look for the same file in the Ubuntu file system (probably `/usr/share/qgis/resources`) , make a copy of that too, and replace the Ubuntu with the Windows one. You might need admin rights for that.

You could as well open and edit the srs.db with spatialite gui.

Comment: thank you, I don't know why as GDAL install was successfull. Anyway tried to copy the Win srs.db but I get an error in QGIS Ubuntu, probably due to the difference in versions of QGIS. I'll try to modify the db manually.

Comment: I tried the same, got an error of missing rights. The other way round it works. But my Ubuntu QGIS Master has towgs84 values. I used the 'ubuntugis-unstable' ppa for Lisboa and http://qgismalaysia.blogspot.de/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-qgis-1990-installation.html for Master to install.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this definitively yet, also with a fresh install of QGIS 2.01, towgs parameters are still missing.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong at your side. I have installed QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 from ubuntugis-unstable, version `2.0.1-1~precise1`, and the +towgs84 parameters are there.

Comment: Hi Andre, finally solved here too! Using ubuntugis repository solved, while using http://qgis.org/debian lucid main still installs GDAL 1.7.3 and no +towgs84 parameters for the CRSs of my interest.

Comment: Sure, 'precise' was the one I'd used, I made a mistake with copy&paste now from the QGIS page, sorry.